# Can you get "Open File Location" in right-click menu in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, right-click

Can you get "Open File Location" in the right-click menu in XP?

This is available on some Windows Server editions and in Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the registry

copy the text between the ========= into a text file and then save it, change the extension from .txt to .reg right click it and select merge.

=======================================================

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\File Location]
@="Open &File Location"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\File Location\command]
@="\"explorer.exe\" /select,\"%1\""
```

============================================================

[or download the reg files from here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-get-windows-vista-and-7s-open-file-location-option-in-xp/)